# Is it possible to change the toolbar icons in gVim?

Tags: vim, gvim

Is it possible to change the toolbar icons in gVim (without patching the exe)?  It seems like you can change everything else, and they are so ugly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depening on which OS and which widget library you are using, the default icons may be determined by your current theme.  I know at least the GNOME GUI for Vim is this way.

Beyond that, you can manually edit `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim` and specify icon files for each ToolBar menu item.  See "`:help toolbar-icon`".